# Delete from GROUP BY with multiple GROUP columns

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a simple table consisting of `id, channel_id, value` and `timestamp`:

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
`id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`channel_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`timestamp` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`value` float NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `IDX_ADF3F36372F5A1AA` (`channel_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2126679551
```

The combination of `channel_id,timestamp` MUST be unique but the table has gotten corrupted. My ultimate goal is to add a unique index which fails due to the duplicates.

The duplicates are:

```
select channel_id,timestamp,count(*) cnt 
from data 
group by channel_id,timestamp having cnt>1
```

How can I delete the duplicates? I'm stuck since obviously I can't get the row id from the duplicates sub select?

**UPDATE** I could probably do

```
delete d1.* from data d1 join data d2 on d1.channel_id=d2.channel_id and d1.timestamp=d2.timestamp where d1.id != d2.id;
```

but since the table has almost 1 billion records a cross-product does not seem like a good idea?

Comment: i would use d1.id > d2.id  but that is the price of not using a backup, you have to run these. also try a dry run where you select the doubles or triplets  and see which they are, it is the same wuery with the join

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! Give us the entire structure of your data table.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you could drop the `channel_id` index and replace it with one that has `(channel_id, timestamp)` - and give it the name data_channel_ts_ix - your current name will produce puzzling and meaningless error messages. I would not use `timestamp` as a field name - use something_meaningful_ts maybe... It's a MySQl keyword. If your data is timestamped, then use a timestamp - you can use the non-standard timestamp(3) (not sure here - maybe deprecated...?).

Answer (score 1):

```sql
DELETE t1
FROM data t1
JOIN data t2 USING (channel_id,timestamp)
WHERE t1.id > t2.id
```

Comment: all answers should have a short explanation

Comment: Cleaner written but the same plan as the delete from the Update above unless I misunderstand?

Comment: @andig The code in your Update is wrong. If dups exists then all dups will be deleted and none will be saved (rather than my code).

Comment: Thank you! I have not updated as commented above.

Answer (score 1):

Corruption!  `AUTO_INCREMENT=2126679551`  `INT` has a limit of 2G!  You could change it to `BIGINT`.  But, read on; I have an even better solution (namely to get rid of `id`):

I recommend replacing your two indexes with these two:

```
PRIMARY KEY(channel_id, timestamp),
INDEX(id)
```

That will help in many of your activities, plus Akina's suggestion, and it will replace Vérace's suggestion.

This is based on `id` being there only to provide a unique PK, and that most queries (read or write) are based on `channel_id`, often in a time range.

If this is sensor data, and you can be sure that there are not two readings in the same 'second', then get rid of `id` completely.  This will shrink the table and speed up all queries.  (Akina's `t1.id > t2.id` would become `t1.timestamp > t2.timestamp`, etc.)

Another tip.  I assume you have only a small number of "channels"?  `INT` takes 4 bytes; `TINYINT UNSIGNED` takes 1 byte and allows values up to 255.  `SMALLINT UNSIGNED`: 2 bytes, max 64K.  Etc.

Comment: Good advise. Unfortunately, the table structure is dictated by the ORM, hence ID is not at disposal.

Comment: @andig - You can probably change to BIGINT and/or change the indexes without involving the ORM.  If not, your project is _dead in the water_ when you overflow auto_increment.

Comment: thank you so much. Turns out that Doctrine ORM (php) has meanwhile implemented DDC-117 and I can indeed replace the id PK with composite PK. Upgrade is running right now, obviously take a bit for 1bn records ;)